# TFS Projects mapped to actual projects

Tags: tfs, version-control, project, alm

I suspect we have a common hierarchy with many other business in that we have software products and we enhance each product through a series of projects.

We have TFS2015 which we host ourselves.

Given TFS does not seem to support the idea of Product I created a TFS *project* called MyProduct. This 'product' exists in both ALM and SCM.

Next I created my first *real* TFS Project, i.e. I created a TFS project with the same name as the actual project I have to run for my job. I now have two TFS projects,

1. MyProduct - this is my master TFS project which I treat as my Product
2. MyFirstProject - this is my first actual project which I'm executing to enhance my existing product

The source code for MyFirstProject is a copy of the source code in MyProduct and should be merged back to MyProduct at some point or points.

When I am at the end of MyFirstProject I want to move the open work items into my Product TFS Project, i.e. MyProduct, including,

1. Descoped MyFirstProject stories which I want to keep in my product backlog
2. Bugs which are detected but not fixed in MyFirstProject
3. Epics/features which are added during MyFirstProject

Next I want to start MySecondProject, etc etc.

Hopefully this is enough detail around how I believe regular products/projects work and my question is, am I using TFS correctly with this approach? It does not seem natural in that my new TFS projects are not an SCM branch they are a new SCM project and moving work items between projects isn't an obliviously easy thing to do.

It feels like I'm missing the point of the TFS project structure.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd like to introduce **Team Project Collection** and **Team Projects**.

   - **A Team Project Collection** is a group of team projects. When you install TFS, a default collection is created to contain all team projects.
   - **A team project** is a collection of source code, work items, build
     definitions, release definitions, manual tests, etc. You can have
     multiple Team Projects per Collection. You create a team project to establish a repository for source code and a place for a group of developers and teams to plan, track progress, and collaborate on building software solutions. Team projects differ from software application projects or solutions. (*Please clarify the TFS project you mentioned in post is a team project or oftware application projects*.)
2. According to your description, `MyProduct` and `MyFirstProject` should have [branch](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-branches-isolate-risk-team-foundation-version-control) relationship. So you can create a project A under a team project X, then branch project A to meet your requirement.
3. Work items is under a team project, not a single software application project. In order to achieve what you want, you can create [Teams](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/scale/multiple-teams) and [Areas](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/modify-areas-iterations) and assign work items to different Area.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. If the naming & structure of elements in TFS is as far from mapping to what I regard as the conventional Product->Projects model then TFS then maybe it is time to look at other tools.

Comment: Please clarify the TFS project you mentioned in post is a team project or oftware application projects?